# Using '&' in ajax form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am submitting a form using `.ajax()`.

The current script contains:

```
data: dataString,
```

`dataString` contains:

```
var list    = $('.listsummary').val()
```

The class `listsummary` belongs to a `textarea` which users fill in,
or will be (partially) filled in dynamically through a different script.

The problem is that users nearly all of the time use the '&' sign, for example:

```
Potato & Patota blah blah blah
```

This screws up the `dataString` allowing to post everything written before the first '&' is found.

How can I achieve that the var `list` will be properly sent to the PHP handler in order to store the entire `textarea` content into the database WITH the use of '&'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encode the string with [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
var list = $('.listsummary').val();
var urlEncoded = encodeURIComponent(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options. Either pack the data as an object:

```
data: { list: $('.listsummary').val() }
```

Or encode the URI components:

```
var dataString = "list=" + encodeURIComponent($('.listsummary').val());
```

Comment: michael added a relative response, I used his sollution which worked for me, Still thank you for the response!

Comment: No worries, he was faster than me :P

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of injections. This is a simple problem, but there are multiple approaches that you can take:

1. If your data is simple unstructured text, you should set contentType to text/plain or application/octet-stream:

   ```
   $.ajax({
     ....
     data: "Hello & world",
     contentType: "text/plain",
     ...
   });
   ```
2. If your data is key values structured, then you should encode your data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. This can be achieved in JQuery by passing a JavaScript key-value object to data:

   ```
   $.ajax({
     ....
     data: { text: "Hello & World", location: "Boston" },
     ...
   });
   ```
3. If your data has more complex structure, you should encode your data in the most appropriate Content Type (e.g. JSON, XML, CSV) and set contentType to (e.g. "application/json", "application/xml", "text/csv")

   ```
   $.ajax({
     ....
     data: JSON.stringify(["Hello & world", {"Hello & World"}]),
     contentType: "application/json",
     ...
   });
   ```

--

On the PHP side, if you need to process anything other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, you'll need to read the request body directly as a string. Which can be fine with this code:

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Or if you have PECL:

```
$body = http_get_request_body();
```

If you use a web framework, they probably also have ways to process custom content types. Check the documentation of your web framework.